# Kivy - Update a label with sensor data?

Tags: python, label, kivy

New to kivy, and OOP.

I'm trying to update a label in kivy with data I pull from a temp sensor.  The code that pulls in the sensor data is in labeltempmod.  I created a function getTheTemp() that is called every second.  In the function I try to assign the text of the label via Label(text=(format(thetemp)), font_size=80).  The program ignores this.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
#This is a test to see if I can write the temp to label
import labeltempmod
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

def getTheTemp(dt):
        thetemp =  labeltempmod.readtemp()
        Label(text=(format(thetemp)), font_size=80)
        print thetemp

class LabelWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass

class labeltestApp(App):
    def build(self):

        # call get_temp 0.5 seconds
        Clock.schedule_interval(getTheTemp, 1)

        return LabelWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    labeltestApp().run()
```

Here is the kivy language file:

```
<LabelWidget>:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        TextInput:
                id: my_textinput
                font_size: 80
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 100
                text: 'default'
        FloatLayout:
                Label:
                        id: TempLabel
                        font_size: 150
                        text: 'Temp Test'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but you never update something You are just creating another label

Try this:

```
class LabelWidget(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LabelWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.getTheTemp, 1)

    def getTheTemp(self, dt):
        thetemp =  labeltempmod.readtemp()
        self.ids.TempLabel.text = thetemp
        print thetemp

class labeltestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return LabelWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    labeltestApp().run()
```

*Update* : for your last request, I think the best way to do that is:

```
...
class LabelWidget(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LabelWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.Thetemp = None
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.getTheTemp, 1)

    def getTheTemp(self, dt):
        if self.Thetemp is None:
            self.thetemp =  labeltempmod.readtemp()
        else:
            self.thetemp =  labeltempmod.readtemp(self.theTemp)
        self.ids.TempLabel.text = str(self.thetemp)
```

Comment: Thank you, you wonderful person!  That works.  I had to add format(thetemp) to those interested.  The label text only accepts strings.  OOP is a little confusing to this noob.  But I'll keep trying to figure it out.

Comment: I'm using a temperature sensor that isn't very precise.  I'd like to introduce a first order lag filter to smooth out the readings.  This introduces the need to pass the old temp back to the labeltempmod.readtemp().  So that means that the getTheTemp(self, dt) needs to return the temp.  The getTheTemp(self, dt) is called by clock.schedule line.  How would I return the temp to the __init__ function so it can be sent back to getTheTemp, the next time it is called, so it can be sent to labeltempmod.readtemp(thetemp)?

Comment: Thank your for taking the time help me out.  That worked! I'm able to pass data around now.  So if I'm understanding this correctly, working backwards, the labeltestApp() is ran.  labeltestApp() has a method called build(), which returns LabelWidget().  When the labeltestApp() returns LabelWidget() it has created an instance of LabelWidget()?  And this instance is held in memory never getting destroyed, so self.theTemp variable in the instance is always in memory and can be called at any time?

Why is labeltestApp() even needed?  why not just call LabelWidget().run()?